# Offset when popping a modal window (colorbox) on IE7 with this CSS

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-7, colorbox

I want to pop a modal window using colorbox.

The CSS contained in the .htm file that is popping, is working well except on IE7 (I'm using IE10 console with IE7 standarts to see it).

Here's the code of it (simplified sketch - I need to use these and additional DIV layout for design purposes):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
#wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-color: #06C;
    color: #565656;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-color: #093;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
    padding-bottom: 999999px;
    margin-bottom: -999999px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the problem stems only from this file, because it works fine on IE7 as well, when I try to pop a window with this simple code:

```
<div style="height:250px; width:700px; background-color:#069;">
</div>
```

The problem:
Instead of popping the modal window at the center of the window,
It is popped with like a 3000px offset to the right, so you have to scroll to the right in order to see the modal window.

Is there a solution for this?

I've tried removing `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` and there was no offset, but then the window looked messed up on mainstream browsers.

Comment: Why are you trying to make anything compatible with that junk? I suppose if you really wanted to accomplish it, you could set a fixed position for IE browsers specifically

Comment: I want the code to be as cross-browser compliant as possible; there's no need for all IE browsers, only IE7. I'm not sure how to construct it with fixed position...